# Split text in Java

Tags: java, split

input text:

```
inptext = "inp1(A, Var1), inp1(B,Var1)"
```

expected output:

```
optext = "inp1(A, Var1)", "inp1(B,Var1)"
```

Code:

```
String [] splitText = inptext.split(", ");
for (String obj:splitText )
{
   System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Current output:

```
inp1(A
Var1)
.
.
```

Interpreting the current output:

```
optext = "inp1(A", "Var1)"
```

Please suggest me on correcting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Regex` lookahead to achieve this, e.g.:

```
String inptext = "inp1(A, Var1), inp1(B,Var1)";
String[] tokens = inptext.split("(?<=\\)),\\s");
for(String token : tokens){
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have space after the comma in the input "like inp1" you can use this:

```
String inptext = "inp1(A, Var1), inp1(B,Var1)";
        String[] tmp = inptext.split("\\), ");
        for (String a : tmp) {
            if (!a.substring(a.length()-1).equals(")"))
                a += ")";
            System.out.println(a);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could combine [`String#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) and [`String#indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) to retrieve the required data.

```
String inptext = "inp1(A, Var1), inp1(B,Var1)";
String firstResult = inptext.substring(0,inptext.lastIndexOf(", "));
String secondResult = inptext.substring(inptext.lastIndexOf(", ")).replace(", ","");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split with `,` that is not between `()` so you can use this regex `,(?![^(]*\))` :

```
String inptext = "inp1(A, Var1), inp1(B,Var1)";
String spl[] = inptext.split(",(?![^(]*\\))");
```

**Output**

```
[inp1(A, Var1),  inp1(B,Var1)]
```